# Can you help me detect missing directive (extension method not found)

Tags: system.reactive

I am starting to play with rx extension for .NET and downloaded some sources.

Basic examples works fine, however there is a function causing an error apparently because an extension method is not declared (should be imported with some directive)

The line of code causing the error is the 2nd one (list.Run) in the commented source (I commented to be able to compile):

```
/*

    protected static void WriteListToConsole<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string name) {

      list.Run(

        value => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", name, value),

        () => Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed", name));

    }

     */
```

it looks like Rx defines somewhere an ext. method Run to IEnumerable but I am not importing it.

I installed Rx v2.0.3 SDK.msi , added references in my project to all System.Reactive.* I found  and used:

```
 using System;
 using System.Reactive.Subjects;
 using System.Reactive.Linq;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I also tried use the Nuget rx.main and ix.main  packages in my project but the error is always there.

Searching on google IEnumerable + Run gives me no info.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that is a very old sample you are looking at.

This is now replaced with the extension method `ForEach` which can be found in the `System.Linq` namespace in the `System.Interactive` dll (IX-Main nuget I think).

You will also note that the *OnCompleted* function parameter is gone, cause well it was a silly idea. The new code should look like:

```
protected static void WriteListToConsole<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string name) 
{
    list.ForEach(value => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", name, value));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed", name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lee!
I am very new to RX so I was not aware the method was obsolete. Pity the doc online (MSDN) does not mention it, it would be nice an explanation of the old method with a big disclaimer "DISCONTINUED" and a link pointing to the new method. This would make things easier  for newbies like me. But fortunately there are the good stackoverflow and experts like you :) 
ps I'm enjoying your book ;)